# I am shia, can I do tayammum even when water is available

Tags: halal-haram

When having ejaculation during sleep. Can we do tayammun for fajar prayer. Even water is available and also have time for ghusal. But, cannot do ghusal at that time because some kind of serious embarrassment.please answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, tayammum can be done only if there is no water. There is no need of any embarrassment. If you don't ejaculate for sometime, nocturnal emission happens in sleep. One solution is to ejaculate once in a while when you are awake so you don't have to mess your bed.

> "... Allāh intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship
> ... " Quran 2:185